# Find words that start with an underscore

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

How can I select all property names that starts with an underscore and replace it with the same property name but without the underscore? It's a very tedious task and I want to use the **VS2012 find and replace function** to make it easy.

**Edit:**

I managed to select all property names with underscores with this regex

```
(?<!\w)_\w+
```

But how to replace it with the same class name excluding the underscore?

Comment: What language is your project in - c# / c++/cli ?

Comment: Write a regular expression. Plenty enough tutorials on the subject. Even a couple of web sites like http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @mockinterface It is written in C#.

Comment: It is either \1 or perhaps \0 (try you always have CTRL-Z) Meybe $ instead of \

Comment: what you have try?, share your code

Comment: Don't use a look-behind assertion for this, you can simply use a word boundary instead: \b_\w+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find `(?<!\w)_` and replace it with nothing.

Noticed that the replace field treats regex only as a string.

Answer (score 1):

In programming C#:

```
withoutUnderscore = Regex.Replace("_test", @"(?<!\w)_(\w+)", "\1");
```

**Edit #1**

In Visual Studio Find and Replace dialog:

1-Type `(?<!\w)_{\w+}` in **Find What** field

2-Type `\1` in **Replace with** field

[image]

Comment: I think he is using the CTRL-H on VS. Nowt to do with writing a program per se.

Comment: @EdHeal OP should clarify then his need exactly. I'll edit my answer about that too.

Comment: Quote "... I want to use the VS2012 find and replace function to make it easy." Seems obvious to me

Comment: @EdHeal According to comments OP noticed about the language, so I considered it.

Comment: That is better +1. Do not have VS on this lap top yet

Comment: I tried to apply the parameters of your code on the VS2012 Find and Replace, but it's replacing the property name literally with an "\1" although I selected 'Use Regular Expressions'.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below regex in the appropriate field inside `Find and Replace` window:

```
Find what: <_{[A-Za-z0-9]+}
Replace with: \1
```